# Build time optimization using extern templates

Tags: c++, templates, extern

I'm trying to optimize my build time using extern templates because I have a lot of generated headers that contain typedefs to a template class.

The template class

```
// TypeID.h

template <typename T>
class TypeID
{
public:
    TypeID(/* <some parameters> */);

    bool isNull() const;
    // ... many other methods
};

template <typename T>
TypeID<T>::TypeID(/* <some parameters> */)
{
    // impl
}

template <typename T>
bool TypeID<T>::isNull() const
{
    // impl
}

// same for the rest of the methods
```

Example of generated header

```
// NamedID.h

#include "TypeID.h"

typedef TypeID</* some type */> NamedID;
```

There are many (~2k) headers like NamedID with different types and they're included throughout the project.

I changed the code generator to add this line above the typedef:

```
extern template class TypeID</* some type */>;
```

and in addition to the header files, it now also generates a cpp where all the extern templates have a corresponding

```
template class TypeID</* some type */>;
```

Due to the number of headers and how many times they're used in the project I expected a big difference in compile time (at least something noticeable) but there's no difference.

I ran several runs of the build with and without this change and all of them take 2h 30m +/-2m.

Did I implement this wrong ? Am I expecting too much ?

My environment:

- RHEL 7.7
- GCC 8.3.1
- CMake + ninja, no ccache, no icecream/distcc

Comment: The compiler still has to parse the templates which is possibly what is taking the time, you've only eliminated any duplicate code generation. You might want to experiment with link time code generation.

Comment: Another option is to move as much of `TypeID` as possible into a base class which is not templated

Comment: @AlanBirtles There's not much I can move into a base class. Could you give more info regarding link time code generation?

Comment: actually looks like link time code generation generally makes builds slower

Comment: also it seems like LTCG is a MSVC feature, I'm on linux and using gcc

Comment: gcc has it too they just call it link time optimisation